# Use querySelectorAll to add a prefix to image source

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I am trying to use the weserv.nl image proxy service to load the images using their cloud servers, and don't loat the original img src image. It is to late to rewrite the src for all images and I also don't want to use jQuery for this, as my intention is to make the site faster, not slower to load.
So what I want is for the img src not to load the original image, instead add a prefix to the src and load the result. Fiddle example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qygc4nmq/). The hard part is that the images don't have id or a class assigned.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("div.separator img");
for (var i = items.length; i--;) {
    var img = items[i];
    img.src = img.src.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
    img.src='https://images.weserv.nl?url='+img.src+'&w=120';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the images doesn't have classes or Ids attached, still you can refer the parent tag and get all the images which you want to replace.

Also in your code, you are setting the src attribute twice. Which is not required. When you're replacing the `//` just store it to a variable later set it to img.src

As per your fiddle, you've two divs, so i'm using `div img` as selector to change the src

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("div img");
for (var i = items.length; i--;) {
    var img = items[i],
        src = img.src.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
    img.src='https://images.weserv.nl?url='+src+'&w=120';
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/88j19mjh/)**

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, it did the trick. Can view at http://www.robotfx.ro. One more question, if you don't mind: How to make the browser load only the proxified image and not the original src? Is it possible?

Comment: Great! glad to help. Enjoy :)